# Spatial joining two polygon objects in R?

Tags: r, spatial-join

I want to combine voter precinct data with school zone data. Precinct boundaries do not line up neatly with school zone boundaries in all cases.

Code look something like this:

```
library(rgdal)
library(tigris)
library(sf)

precincts <- readOGR(
  dsn = "input/SOEShapefiles2020/SOEShapefiles2020.shp",
  layer = "SOEShapefiles2020"
)

precinctDemos <- read.csv("input/data/Party registration in voting precincts.csv")
mPrecDemo <- geo_join(
  spatial_data = precincts,
  data_frame = precinctDemos,
  by_sp = "PRECINCT",
  by_df = "Precinct",
  how = "inner"
)

elemZones <- readOGR(
  dsn = "input/2020-21_Attendance_Boundaries/2020-21_ElemAttendance.shp",
  layer = "2020-21_ElemAttendance"
)
elemZones$MSID_ELEM <- as.numeric(elemZones$MSID_ELEM)
attendance <- read.csv("elementary school attendance.csv")

mElem <- geo_join(
  spatial_data = elemZones,
  data_frame = attendance,
  by_sp = "MSID_ELEM",
  by_df = "School.",
  how = "inner"
)
```

So `mElem` and `mPrecDemo` are each "Large SpatialPolygonsDataFrame" objects. How do I perform a spatial join to bring the two objects together? I want to be able to estimate the number of voters in each school zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package `sf` (simple features) makes it easier and more understandable to deal with spatial objects in R; besides that, it reads shapefiles in way faster than `readOGR` and returns these data.frame like objects of `sf` class.

In your case, just converting the two `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` and joining spatially would be like this:

```
library(sf)
mPrecDemo = st_as_sf(mPrecDemo)
mElem = st_as_sf(mElem)
st_join(mPrecDemo, mElem)
```

In this case, you get the features of the first with the data of the spatially intersecting feature, if any. Check `?st_join` to see the available predicates.

For translating the rest of your code into `sf` :

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
precincts <- read_sf("input/SOEShapefiles2020/SOEShapefiles2020.shp")

precinctDemos <- read.csv("input/data/Party registration in voting precincts.csv")

# I think you are rather looking for a left_join, otherwise just change for inner_join
mPrecDemo <- left_join(precincts, precinctDemos, by = c("PRECINCT" = "Precinct"))

elemZones <- read_sf("input/2020-21_Attendance_Boundaries/2020-21_ElemAttendance.shp")

elemZones$MSID_ELEM <- as.numeric(elemZones$MSID_ELEM)
attendance <- read.csv("elementary school attendance.csv")

mElem <- left_join(elemZones, attendance, by = c("MSID_ELEM" = "School."))

st_join(mPrecDemo, mElem)
```

Comment: I got this error: `Error in st_geos_binop("intersects", x, y, sparse = sparse, prepared = prepared,  : 
  st_crs(x) == st_crs(y) is not TRUE`.

Comment: so you must re-project one layer, you can try: `mElem = st_transform(mElem, st_crs(mPrecDemo))`